# Extracting data from PDF file Python

Tags: python, json, pypdf

I have been trying to extract some data from a PDF file that looks like this one:

[image]

From there I would need to extract and then organize it in a JSON format like in this sample:

[image]

So far what I have done is reading extracting the data from the PDF using `PyPDF2` then getting the whole text of the file as a string:

[image]

Any ideas on how to manipulate this string and then organize it as in the JSON sample shown above?

The link to the PDF file is this one https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/blob/199314/07ca43dc0e5c95411b95a51b9ac3a11a/dtauslandsvertretungenliste-data.pdf